# Не работает код по неизвестной мне причине

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
user_name = int(input("Введите своё имя или ник-нейм : "))

hello_bot = int(input("Привет,дорогой друг.Меня зовут Petya, и я программа NicKoN (-а) , как зовут тебя? "))

a = "Программист"
c = "Верстальщик"

int(input(f"{a} , {c} ."))

interests_bot = int(input("Какая профессия тебе больше нравится из приведённого выше списка? "))


if (f"interests_bot = {a}")
    print(f"Круто,{user_name} !Программист очень востребованная профессия.")
elif: (f"interests_bot = {c}")
    print(f"Круто,{user_name} !Вы будете реализовать и воплощать визуальное решение информации.")
else:
    print(f"Хорошо,{user_name} .Видимо эти профессии вам не интересны.")


    if (f"interests_bot = {a}")
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Изначально код выглядел так :**

```
user_name = int(input("Введите своё имя или ник-нейм : "))

hello_bot = int(input("Привет,дорогой друг.Меня зовут Petya, и я программа NicKoN (-а) , как зовут тебя? "))

a = "Программист"
c = "Верстальщик"

int(input(f"{a} , {c} ."))

interests_bot = int(input("Какая профессия тебе больше нравится из приведённого выше списка? "))


if interests_bot = a
    print(f"Круто,{user_name} !Программист очень востребованная профессия.")
elif: interests_bot = c
    print(f"Круто,{user_name} !Вы будете реализовать и воплощать визуальное решение информации.")
else:
    print(f"Хорошо,{user_name} .Видимо эти профессии вам не интересны.")
```

Я добавлял скобки , кавычки , форматировал с помощью **f** и ничего не помогало.
Хотелось бы узнать,в чём проблема

Comment: if должен выглядеть так: `if условие:`

Answer (score 4):

уже несколько постов сегодня идет с одним и тем же косяком, как будто из одного примера копируется:

в питоне условие выглядит так:

```
if условие:
    действие
elif условие:
    действия
else:
    действия
```

или

```
if условие: действие (только 1 строка)
elif условие: действия (только 1 строка)
else: действия (только 1 строка)
```

или их комбинация

у вас ошибки:

№1: не стоит двоеточие:

```
if interests_bot = a
```

№2: двоеточие не после условия

```
elif: interests_bot = c
```

№3: в условии нет сравнения, а стоит присваивание:

```
if interests_bot = a
elif: interests_bot = c
```

№4: вы имя пользователя в виде числа будете спрашивать?

```
user_name = int(input("Введите своё имя или ник-нейм : "))

hello_bot = int(input("Привет,дорогой друг.Меня зовут Petya, и я программа NicKoN (-а) , как зовут тебя? "))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if var == "val":
```

А не:

```
if var = "val":
```